# Can I use ANOVA if a sample is not normally distributed

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

My data are not normally distributed. I have to compare three groups for their achievement in skill learning. $n=4$ in each group. I have used three methods ($M1$, $M2$ and $M3$) to teach one skill to developmentally delayed children.

Can I still use ANOVA?

Do I have to use repeated measures of ANOVA or a time series? Please throw some light

Comment: How do you know that your data are not normally distributed? If you only have 4 data points per group, I guess you don't have a lot of power to detect non-normality. Remember that if you want to check normality, you should check it *within* groups, not across all groups.

Answer (score 1):

You do not say whether the *same four children* are taught with *each* method (i.e. child #1 is taught a skill using $M1$ and measured, then child #1 is taught a skill using $M2$ and measured, then child #1 is taught a skill using $M3$ and measured, etc.). Without this vital information, one cannot say whether or not you have a repeated measures design (although, given your sample size, I imagine the answer is yes).

With such a small sample size, I would imagine that violations of the normality assumption could well affect your results. So you might be interested in using a nonparametric variation of oneway ANOVA such as the [Kruskal-Wallis test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) if your data *are not* from a repeated measures design (with [Dunn's test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/dunn-test/info) for *post hoc* comparisons), or using a nonparametric variation of the oneway repeated measure ANOVA such as the [Friedman test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test) if your data *are* from a repeated measures design (I not familiar with this test, but a good nonparametric statistics text should be able to offer *post hoc* procedures).

Because both the Kruskal-Wallis and Friedman tests are based on ranks across the whole data set, simply performing a garden variety rank sum test as a *post hoc* procedure ignores the rankings used to produce the omnibus tests. Likewise, the rank sum tests ignore the pooled variance implied by the null hypothesis or both Kruskal-Wallis and Friedman tests.